# Can one time executable scripts be a part of SOLID design?

Tags: database, solid, scripting

Imagine a table `T`, with `2 columns` containing data.  Everyday, one row is added the table.

Now you `add 3rd column` to the table (After adding this column too, one row will be added the table everyday).

Since the column has been added, its value will be `null`. So single time executable script is necessary in-order to update the table and replace `null` based on historical data.

Is such single time executable scripts manageable and scalable in the long run? is this the part of SOLID design?

Comment: I am not sure what relates SOLID and your script concept. I guess you are in some type of server-database environment and your script populate the database? in that case, it seem not a good design from the beginning.

Comment: I am extending the system by adding a column, and not modifying the existing ones. Thats how I bring about SOLID design here.

Comment: With all the respect, it seem to me that you are misunderstanding the concepts of SOLID, or in the best case, applying them in a very exotic way.

Comment: Beware of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Take time to ascertain if the concept is relevant to the problem at hand. [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) is probably a more applicable concept to what you've described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLID is about development and design principles for writing code that needs to be maintained. SOLID is mostly/entirely irrelevant when it comes to actual data used by a program. A one time script to fix/create data is not really related to SOLID at all since by definition it won't be maintained.